# Online index card system

Tags: android, web-apps, knowledge-organization

I would like to organize ideas and quotes and being able to access them online and from devices.

Requirements:

- Ability to attach tags/categories to cards
- Available online and from Android
- Full-text search
- Simple: not overloaded with functionality that I won't use. So it's not like Trello, or more elaborate systems for writing documents/wikis

Google Keep fits the bill exactly, but I cannot use it because I already use Google Keep for some quite different purpose and don't want to mix these use-cases. (Too bad Google Keep doesn't have a notion of "spaces". But, maybe I'll opt in to create a separate Google account just for this purpose.)

Comment: I'm also interested in this topic of a computerized index card file. My intended use would be for storing and cross-referencing data items in research programmes. Like many researchers I have missed logical connections between related facts - and sometimes this resulted in not pursuing more productive lines of enquiry. Doing my research in 1990s I saw others making entries to a physical index card file. But I never saw anyone using their index file to suggest new directions for their research. (This of course may have been done secretely or out of the office.) It happened once then that I miss

Comment: From deleted answer's comment, for posterity: `I ended up using Notion.so – leventov Jan 25, 2021`

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm actually getting away with a single Google Keep account, assigning all the existing notes (which are not index cards or quotes) with a specific tag. It makes the home, unfiltered view of all notes a mess, but this doesn't appear to be a problem yet because in Google Keep it's easy to filter notes by label.

This approach would probably be harder if I used labels for that my original use-case for Google Keep, but luckily I didn't.